# How to set Entity Framework Core Connection timeout?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use EF core. To check a db I run this:

`bool canConnect = await DbContext.CanConnect();`

I'm trying to set the ConnectionTimeout, but EntityFrameworkCore seems to ignore the value and this code runs 50 seconds.

I tried connectionstring :

`"...connect Timeout=1;"` 
or
`"...connection Timeout=1;"`

no result.

I tried in the DbContext:

`Database.SetCommandTimeout(1);`

or in DbContext-Configuration:

````
services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, MyDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options
                    .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Dilos"),
                        sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(1)
                    );
            });
    ```     
            

no result.
How can I do this?
````

Comment: What does CanConnect do?

Comment: Command and Connection timeouts are two distinct things so first confirm you want to set the Connection timeout? You should be able to do it in the connection string, I don't  know what you are experiencing to determine it is not working.

Comment: Also, you are mixing CommandTimeout and Connect Timeout.

Comment: CanConnect is a function of the EF to connect the DB. 
I want to see if the DB exists. I know I mix CommandTimeout and Connect Timeout, but I've just tried different ways

Comment: But what is it you are trying to accomplish? We still don't know if you want to set a command timeout or a connection timeout. If connection, then you are probably not experiencing a timeout because connections are pooled and it will take less than a second to re-connect. Create a bad connection string on purpose and you will experience a timeout.

Comment: I want to test whether a DB can be reached. But it should be quick, now it takes about 50s before I get an error.